# How can I stop the execution of a specific method by press for example on StopButton in WinForm

Tags: c#

I have 2 buttons the first one it's name "Continuous" .. the second one "Stop"

I want to call a method when press the continuous button :

```
private void continuous_Click(object sender ,EvantArgs e) 

 {    // how to get stop event

while(!StopEvent) method();



  }
```

my question is : how can I stop  the execution by pressing the stop button ??

Comment: Using a tight **while** loop like this is going to freeze your UI and prevent you from clicking the **Stop** button.

Comment: Use BackgroundWorker class. Create an instance of this in your continue_Click handler, then stop it in your Stop click handler. Read about BackgroundWorder on msdn.